# Cравнение множества последовательных данных по Datetime

Tags: oracle, sql

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой, в силу своей неопытности, которую решить не могу. Надеюсь на участие. Суть задачи:

1) Для набора "операций", описанных в существующей таблице ITGTRANSHIST, присвоены следующие значения (перечисляю только те, по которым и будет происходить сравнение и выборка):

```
№ операции                   | TRANSID       | type=DECIMAL
время операции               | transdatetime | type=date ('dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss')
№ устр на кот. была операция | Deviceid      | type=DECIMAL
```

2) Необходимо: для каждого Устройства (Deviceid) вычислить время, за которое не осуществлялось ни одной операции в течении 2-х часов. Т.е. разница по времени между 2-мя последовательными номерами операций TRANSID для каждого устройства превышает 2 ч.

С выборкой всех операций за определенное число проблем не возникает:

```
select transid, transdatetime, deviceid
  from itgtranshist
 where deviceid between 327681 and 327788
   and transdatetime > to_date('15.08.11 00:00:00','dd.mm.yy.hh24:mi:ss')
 order by deviceid;
```

Вопрос - как сравнить, найти, грубо говоря "время простоя" на данном устройстве?

Comment: Язык программирования и тип БД мы должны угадать? Проставьте их в метках, всем будет проще.

Comment: Пардон-с! Уже не первый форум в поисках ответа, посему уже и упустил это важную составляющую! SQL. оракловая БД

Comment: Нет нет, я о том и говорю - запрос возьмет метки и соответственно время последних событий, которые перебирал для данного устройства. А нужные, которые по разнице во времени в искомые 2 часа существуют хронологически где нибудь в середине массива данных, остаются не выбранными! запрос просто показывает, что - да, таковое там присутствует, но КОГДА - неизвестно! А записей для каждого устройства от единиц тысяч до десятков тысяч. Первый предложенный код я уже таким образом модифицировал, и когда результата не получил образно набросал конструкцию, где бы возможно существовал условный переход в цик

Comment: эскьюзе. в запрос вкралась ошибка. вторая колонка - метка предыдущего события  `select t1.transdatetime as a1, t2.transdatetime as a2 from` ...
возможно, я просто не въехал в задачу

Comment: а вобще - есть ли вариант вставить в запрос условный оператор, который бы формировал столбец с нужным transdate?

Comment: Конечно. используйте CASE WHEN .. THEN ... END
По ведению - не надо на собственный вопрос отвечать, пишите комментарии

Comment: и про эти и про другие операторы написано много, но нигде нет примеров КАК их использовать в теле запроса SELECT. вот в чем суть вопроса

Comment: От балды

select
 case when f<0 then -1
when f=0 then 0
else 1
end as Sample
from t

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

Если идентификаторы наблюдений идут строго последовательно на каждом устройстве, то соединение что-то вроде

```
select *
  from itgtranshist t1
    join itgtranshist t2 on t2.deviceid = t1.deviceid and t2.transid = (t1.transid-1)
where
(to_date(t1.transdatetime, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(t2.transdatetime, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 1440 > 120
```

Comment: Спасибо! Отчасти  запрос работает - в том плане, что факт пропуска он показывает. Однако, я так и не нашел (может не там искал) конструкцию, исползующего условный переход внутри запроса, для выбора времени НАЧАЛА и ОКОНЧАНИЯ простоя на устройстве.

Comment: Логически как то так...но не работает!

select (to_date(t1.transdatetime, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(t2.transdatetime, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')), 
        t2.deviceid, a1, a2
  from itgtranshist t1 join itgtranshist t2 on t2.deviceid = t1.deviceid and t2.transid = (t1.transid-1) 
where
 (to_date(t1.transdatetime, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(t2.transdatetime, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 1440 > 120
        BEGIN  
 a1=t1.transdatetime 
 a2=t2.transdatetime
 END;

Comment: не, ну так нельзя конечно, смотрите синтаксис select. таблица t2 - это предыдущее событие, t1 - следующее. надо просто взять метки времени из каждой таблицы
select t1.transdatetime as a1,  t1.transdatetime as a2
  from itgtranshist t1 
    join itgtranshist t2 on t2.deviceid = t1.deviceid and t2.transid = (t1.transid-1) 
where 
(to_date(t1.transdatetime, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(t2.transdatetime, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 1440 > 120

Answer (score 0):

Смотри на аналитические функции LAG и LEAD:

- [Oracle/PLSQL: Lead Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lead.php)
- [SQL: Аналитические функции](https://docs.google.com/Doc?id=ddd4649x_4ggr4npc3&pli=1).